# How can one dynamically place requirements upon an <xs:any /> block using multiple schemata?

Tags: xml, schema

Consider the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fooDb version="1.0.0.0" xmlns="http://tempurl.org/2013/01/Example">
  <provider>Some Provider</provider>
  <connectionSettings xmlns="http://tempurl.org/2013/01/Example.SomeProvider">
    <protocol>https</protocol>
    <server>contoso-server</server>
    <port>8080</port>
    <project>Tailspin Toys</project>
  </connectionSettings>
</fooDb>
```

Basically, I have this `<connectionSettings>` element, which I would like clients to be able to customize. I don't want the overall "Example" project to know about what a specific provider does for its connection settings. My first attempt at a schema for this looked like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="ExampleConfiguration"
    xmlns="http://tempurl.org/2013/01/Example"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://tempurl.org/2013/01/Example"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <!-- Root element for configurations. -->
  <xs:element name="fooDb">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="provider" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element ref="connectionSettings" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="version" type="version" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="provider" type="xs:string" />

  <!-- Individual providers provide their own connection settings. -->
  <xs:element name="connectionSettings">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any processContents="strict" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                namespace="##other" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <!-- Requires that an element be empty. -->
  <xs:simpleType name="empty">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value=""/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <!-- Current version is 1.0.0.0. -->
  <xs:simpleType name="version">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="1.0.0.0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

A specific provider, let's call it "SomeProvider", defines its own connection settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="SomeProviderConfiguration"
    xmlns="http://tempurl.org/2013/01/Example.SomeProvider"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://tempurl.org/2013/01/Example.SomeProvider"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="connectionSettings">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="protocol" type="protocol" />
        <xs:element name="server" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="port" type="port" />
        <xs:element name="project" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:simpleType name="protocol">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="http" />
      <xs:enumeration value="https" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="port">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
      <xs:maxInclusive value="65535" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

When I try to validate this, I get a failure because the outer schema expects the `<connectionSettings>` node to be defined as part of the "Example" namespace, but it really belongs to the "Example.SomeProvider" namespace (At least as I defined it above).

Is such a thing expressible in schema in this fashion, or do I have to resort to a schema inclusion scheme?

Answer (score 1):

If I go by the sample XML you provided you must not define "connectionSettings" in the "Example" namespace. Your fooDb would look like

```
<xs:element name="fooDb">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="provider" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:any processContents="strict" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                namespace="##other" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But I guess you trying enforce providers to override "connectionSettings" without sharing the same namespace as "Example". I do not think it's possible.

If you really want to ensure "connectionSettings" is part of "Example" namespace then providers needs to tweak their XSD like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="SomeProviderConfiguration"
    xmlns="http://tempurl.org/2013/01/Example.SomeProvider"
    xmlns:par="http://tempurl.org/2013/01/Example"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://tempurl.org/2013/01/Example.SomeProvider"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

        <xs:element name="protocol" type="protocol" />
        <xs:element name="server" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="port" type="port" />
        <xs:element name="project" type="xs:string" />

  <xs:simpleType name="protocol">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="http" />
      <xs:enumeration value="https" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="port">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
      <xs:maxInclusive value="65535" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

or the XML instance must look like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:fooDb xmlns:p="http://tempurl.org/2013/01/Example" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="..."
    xmlns:inc="http://tempurl.org/2013/01/Example.SomeProvider">
  <p:provider>p:provider</p:provider>
    <p:connectionSettings>
      <protocol xsi:type="inc:protocol" xmlns="http://tempurl.org/2013/01/Example.SomeProvider">https</protocol>
      <server xmlns="http://tempurl.org/2013/01/Example.SomeProvider">localhost</server>
      <port xsi:type="inc:port" xmlns="http://tempurl.org/2013/01/Example.SomeProvider">8001</port>
      <project xmlns="http://tempurl.org/2013/01/Example.SomeProvider">example</project>
    </p:connectionSettings>
</p:fooDb>
```